# Abrir um modal de outra classe POO React

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, react

Estou aprendendo JavaScript e POO então posso estar fazendo alguma besteira, estou tentando fazer um navbar e desse navbar abrir diferentes funções de diferentes classes em outros arquivos.

Essa parte onde tem a seta de voltar,  o texto 'produtos' e os icones é o header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/coEG3.png
O resto, pra baixo é da página formProduct

**Código full:**

src/components/Header/index.js: https://hastebin.com/acaboqeyog.cs

src/pages/formProduct/index.js:  https://hastebin.com/sixitemori.cs

Do jeito que eu fiz eu consigo executar a função oi, que pega um state e da um alert na tela, mas não consigo executar a função .new que abre um modal para criar um novo produto... Por que?

No caso, no header (src/components/Header/index.js), na linha 173, eu consigo usar:

```
<Ionicon icon="md-add-circle" fontSize="35px" color="#0069d9" onClick={ products.oi } />
```

Mas não consigo usar:

```
<Ionicon icon="md-add-circle" fontSize="35px" color="#0069d9" onClick={ products.new } />
```

Por que? O que eu to fazendo de errado?

Comment: Cara, tenta colocar as imagens e os códigos necessários para reprodução do problema direto na pergunta ao invés de utilizar links externos, leia também [mcve].

Comment: Eu não entendi o porque de criar uma nova instancia, não seria o caso de apenas renderizar a class formproduct como modal? Ou entao criar um hoc no modal e passar o component que você quer renderizar para dentro do mesmo.

Comment: Os códigos estão no hastebin
A instancia foi só uma forma que eu encontrei de executar funções da outra classe que está em outro arquivo
O estranho é que eu consigo executar a função Oi, mas não consigo executar a new que cria um modal
Por que? Não da pra executar um modal de outra classe?